# Merge first two of a dataframe and create new header

Tags: pandas, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1': ['abc', 'qrt', 130, 200, 190, 210], 
    'Col2': ['xyz','tuv', 130, 200, 190, 210],
    'Col3': ['pqr', 'set', 130, 200, 190, 210],})
```

I wish to take the first two rows of the dataframe, merge them separated by a hyphen and convert them into a new header. I tried

```
df.columns = np.concatenate(df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1])
df.columns = new_header
```

But that does not seem to work. The output should look like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'abc_qrt': [ 130, 200, 190, 210], 
    'xyz_tuv': [130, 200, 190, 210],
    'pqr_set': [ 130, 200, 190, 210],})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
df = df.T.set_index([0,1]).T
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df
Out[308]: 
  abc_qrt xyz_tuv pqr_set
2     130     130     130
3     200     200     200
4     190     190     190
5     210     210     210
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the first two rows, join them with `_` and then set columns of the rest with that:

```
df.iloc[2:].set_axis(df.iloc[:2].agg("_".join), axis=1)
```

to get

```
  abc_qrt xyz_tuv pqr_set
2     130     130     130
3     200     200     200
4     190     190     190
5     210     210     210
```